# rebind org-mode movements to hyper/function key?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, dot-emacs, aquamacs

On OSX I am accustomed to using shift-arrow to highlight regions, and option-arrow to navigate through my text word-by-word, i.e. by whole words at a time.

This works very nicely in Aquamacs Emacs org-mode EXCEPT: 
1. when I hold down shift and option at the same time to highlight regions whole-words at a time
2. when I'm in a heading or list

I want a way to navigate by whole-word that doesn't conflict with org-mode's headline movement commands.

How do I unbind meta-arrow and meta-return from all the org-mode navigation, and rebind them to hyper (function)?

That way I could do org-mode heading navigation using hyper-arrow and hyper-return, and option-arrow would be free for whole-word navigation even when highlighting regions or when within special contexts.

Answer (score 1):

To change key bindings for keys in org mode, use keymap `org-mode-map`.  E.g.

```
 (define-key org-mode-map YOURKEY YOURCOMMAND)
```

Comment: But how do I unbind M-return, M-right, M-left, and the existing org movement commands?

Comment: You can unbind a key in a given keymap by binding it to `nil`. E.g., `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "M-<right>") nil)` or just `(define-key org-mode-map [M-right]) nil)`.